# PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value --- when trying to run cron

Tags: 7

I am using search file attachments module, after adding some content with attached files, when I try to run cron the whole site is not indexing. But when I add content with just title and body it is working file, if I attached a file to node then I am unable to search the file contents.

Log report says

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string
>   value: '\xF0\x9D\x90\xBF ...' for column 'data' at row 1: INSERT INTO
>   {search_dataset} (sid, type, data, reindex) VALUES
>   (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1,
>   :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3); Array (
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 26 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => file
>   [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => filename 6 hl bu slides r2 may 2 2012pdf
>   content head loss back up slides head loss calcula3ons casa grande
>   requires a correla3on to determine head loss over the range of
>   relevant condi3ons debris loads fiber par3culate microporous chemical
>   flow rate temperature npsh margin slide 2 porous media head loss
>   correla3ons porous media head loss correla3ons follows the classical
>   porous media ﬂow equa3ons dp a u b u2 dl where a coeﬃcient for viscous
>   term b coeﬃcient for iner3a term nureg cr 6224 correla3on is a semi
>   theore3cal correla3on developed based on ﬂat plate ver3cal loop head
>   loss tes3ng with nukon ﬁberglass ﬁbers nominally 7 micron diameter and
>   bwr suppression pool sludge iron oxide nominally 10 micron diameter
>   nureg cr 6224 experimental data were performed at ﬂuid temperatures
>   ranging from 60of to 125of debris bed thicknesses ranging from 125 in
>   to 4 in and approach veloci3es ranging from 15 c s to 15 c s slide 3
>   nureg cr 6224 correla3on where δh head loss c water sv surface to
>   volume ra3o of the debris c2 c3 µ dynamic viscosity of water lbm c sec
>   u ﬂuid approach velocity c sec ρ density of water lbm c3 αm mixed
>   debris bed solidity one minus the porosity δlm actual mixed debris bed
>   thickness in λ 41528x10 5 c water in lbm c2 sec2 conversion factor for
>   english units m m m vmmv lssh δ λ δ 23512 u 1 660u57153 ρ α α µαα
>   slide 4 nureg cr 6224 correla3on the very low approach velocity at stp
>   1 c sec suggests that the head loss will be dominated by the viscous
>   term the viscous term of the nureg cr 6224 correla3on is based on
>   experimental work by c n davies proceedings of ins3tute of mechanical
>   engineers london b1 p 185 1952 for stp condi3ons the nureg cr 6224
>   correla3on could be simpliﬁed to slide 5 mmmv lsh δ λ δ u57153 3512
>   µαα nureg cr 6224 correla3on suppor3ng compression equa3on nureg cr
>   6224 based on w l ingmanson et al internal pressure distribu3on in
>   compressible mats under fluid stress tapi journal vol 42 no 101959 
>         where α and ϒ are empirically based currently α 13
>   and ϒ 38 alterna3ve clint shaﬀer 2005 1    1     where α
>   ϒ and ф are empirically based currently α 65 ϒ 38 and ф 35 1 6224
>   correla3on training session nrc headquarters april 12 2005 slide 6
>   shaﬀer compression alterna3ve 1 slide 7 1 6224 correla3on training
>   session nrc headquarters april 12 2005 head loss correla3on reﬁnements
>   perform ver3cal loop tes3ng to acquire head loss data at stp speciﬁc
>   condi3ons ie low approach velocity and representa3ve ﬁber par3culate
>   loadings adjust correla3on suppor3ng equa3ons to best ﬁt the
>   experimental results determine from integrated chemical eﬀects tests
>   the impact of chemical precipitates on head loss slide 8 strainer
>   geometry calculate strainer area and gap dimensions based on strainer
>   drawings calculate average approach velocity based on total strainer
>   area calculate inters33al volume based on gap dimensions calculate
>   increased approach velocity for large debris loads based on
>   circumscribed strainer area slide 9 strainer dimensions strainer area
>   per train 18185 c2 circumscribed area per train 4190 c2 inters33al
>   volume per train 818 c3 photos of stp pci strainer slide 10 flow rate
>   and temperature input total ﬂow rate through each eccs strainer for
>   the speciﬁc case analyzed maximum of 7020 gpm per train at stp based
>   on 1620 gpm per hhsi pump 2800 gpm per lhsi pump and 2600 gpm per cs
>   pump calculate debris accumula3on on each strainer based on rela3ve
>   ﬂow split calculate pool ﬂuid density and viscosity for a given pool
>   temperature slide 11 npsh margin input npsh margin for each safety
>   injec3on and containment spray pump compare calculated debris bed head
>   loss to the pump npsh margin to determine whether the pump would fail
>   npsh required lhsi pumps 165 c hhsi pumps 161 c cs pumps 164 c npsh
>   available excluding clean strainer and debris losses start of
>   recircula3on 267 f 22 c 24 hours 171 f 42 c 30 days 128 f 51 c slide
>   12 nureg cr 6224 head loss correla3on mixed debris bed solidity the
>   mixed debris bed solidity αm is given by where αo the solidity of the
>   original ﬁber blanket ie the as fabricated solidity η mp mf the
>   par3culate to ﬁber mass ra3o in the debris bed m σ mi is the total
>   par3culate mass lbm ρf the ﬁber density lbm c3 ρp the average
>   par3culate material density lbm c3 σ ρivi σ vi c the head loss induced
>   volumetric compression of the debris inches inch slide 13 nureg cr
>   6224 head loss correla3on sv averaging for mixed debris bed the
>   averaged surface to volume ra3o for a mixed debris bed is given by
>   where svn sv of the nth cons3tuent vn volume of the nth cons3tuent
>   slide 14 sv sqrt σ svn2 vn σ vn [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => 0 ) in
>   search_index() (line 705 of
>   /var/www/vhosts/praappsmgr.com/pilogix/praapps/modules/search/search.module).

Can any one know what is happening and how to fix this?

Comment: For what it's worth, I believe your down votes are due to dumping a huge error message, combined with not much effort shown.

Comment: I want to thank you for posting this question. This pointed me to the solution much faster than results from drupal.org. And letharion thanks for the answer of course :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a completely wild guess, but here goes:

1. You run mysql
2. Your tables are "UTF-8"
3. The data you are inserting into the index contains "unusual" UTF-8 characters.

If those three are true, then there's your problem.

MySQL "cheats" on their UTF-8 implementation. Drupal will always instruct MySQL to create UTF-8 tables, but by default, [UTF-8 in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html) doesn't cover the entire UTF-8.

You will need to manually convert your tables to `utf8mb4`, and then also manually "upgrade"
the connection to mysql whenever you handle this data. I stuck some code [in a sandbox](https://drupal.org/sandbox/Letharion/1729974) at one point that partly addresses this, but it's not generally applicable at this time.

Or you switch to [Postgresql](http://www.postgresql.org/), that actually gets this right by default.

There's an [issue on Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/1314214) for resolving this.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does that mean that UTF handling in MySQL was the issue?